# parallel / concurrent test execution using protractor

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I have 2 test users (will add some more). Some spec files use one and some the other. No 2 test cases can run together if they use the same test user.
 I wanted to execute all my specs in a selenium grid. I eventually decided to group the spec files using one spec user with one chrome instance and the other with the other chrome instance. (For now I will be using only one chrome version)
Now the problem is that both chrome browsers are the same version. How do I separate the 2 group of test cases to run in parallel. E.g test user 1 cases will run on Chrome instance 1 and the other set of test cases on Chrome instance 2. I added an arbitrary browser_version to separate the 2 group in the multicapabilities. I dont think it is working. 
Is there an elegant solution to this.
For debugging, I tried to get the browser verison a particular test was using with the following lines in the test. Its probably not possible.

```
(browser.multiCapabilities["browser_version"]).then(function(v){
  console.log("check:" + v);
})
```

;

But it gives the error. Cannot read property 'browser_version' of undefined.

Following is the protractor config file multicapabilities. I dont use "specs"  property at the level above this.

```
maxSessions: 2,
multiCapabilities: [
{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'browser_version': '11.0',
  shardTestFiles: false,
  maxInstances: 1,
  maxSessions: 1,
  count: 1,
  specs: [ 'test/e2e/VE1-Spec.js', 'test/e2e/VE2-Spec.js' ]
}, {
  shardTestFiles: false,
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'browser_version': '9.0',
  maxInstances: 1,
  maxSessions: 1,
  count: 1,

  specs: ['test/e2e/DG1-Spec.js', 'test/e2e/DG2-Spec.js']
}],
```

Comment: Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 5):

Try the below multiCapabilities configuration. This is working fine for me.

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec1.js','specs/spec2.js','specs/spec3.js']
    },
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec4.js',
            'specs/spec5.js',
            'specs/spec6.js',
        ]
    }
```

The above congfiguration will launch two chrome instance and executes spec1,spec2 and spec3 on chrome instance 1. And remaining 3 specs will be executed on chrome instance 2.

Comment: will that work with just executing `protractor conf.js` ? or needs anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sudharsan. I did not find any documentation for "sequential" property in protractor. Commenting sequential out also made it work.
However when I tried following it worked:

```
maxSessions: 2,
multiCapabilities: [
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
   name: 'CAPABILITY_1',
   logName: 'LOGNAME1_USERNAME1_A',
  shardTestFiles: false,
  maxInstances: 1,
  maxSessions: 1,
  count: 1,
  specs: [ 'test/e2e/VE1-Spec.js', 'test/e2e/VE2-Spec.js' ]
}, {
  shardTestFiles: false,
  'browserName': 'chrome',
   name: 'CAPABILITY_2',
   logName: 'LOGNAME1_USERNAME2_BB,
  maxInstances: 1,
  maxSessions: 1,
  count: 1,
  specs: ['test/e2e/DG1-Spec.js', 'test/e2e/DG2-Spec.js']
}]
```

This seems to remove any confusion between the 2 capabilities in even the log file as each line has the logname of the particular spec to show which capability is executing it. I just wonder in Sudarshan's case he may have a different version of protractor etc.

Finally you can even print your capability (found from config.ts in github) in your code to ensure its working right.

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
  // config.capabilities is the CURRENT capability being run, if
  // you are using multiCapabilities.
  console.log('Executing capability', config.capabilities);
});
```